# Current filename for find/xargs/perl -ne?

Tags: perl, xargs, perlvar

I'm working in the shell, trying to find NUL chars in a bunch of CSV files (that Python's CSV importer is whinging about, but that's for another time) using the so-proud-of-my-ever-clever-self:

```
find ~/path/ -name "*.csv" -print0 | \
xargs -n 1 -0 \
perl -ne 'if(m/\x{00}/){print fileno(ARGV).join(" ",@ARGV).$_;}'
```

Except I see no filename. *Allegedly* the implicit <> operator that `perl -ne` is wrapping my script in is just using `@ARGV` / the `ARGV` filehandle, but neither of the above is giving me the name of the current file.

How do I see the current filename (and, ideally, line number) in the above?

Comment: Why does `xargs -n 1` limit one file per perl process?  If you're using `perl -n` mode and not doing anything very sneaky, it would act the same if xargs allowed giving multiple filenames to the same perl.

Comment: Sorry, it was debugging cruft left in there.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[`$ARGV`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#%24ARGV) is the name of the current file and [`$.`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#%24.) is the current line number; see `perldoc perlvar` and *I/O Operators* in `perldoc perlop`.  (Note that `$.` doesn't reset between files; there's discussion of that in `perldoc -f eof`.)

And I'm not entirely sure what you're trying to accomplish with that `print`; it will give you the filehandle number, which is probably 3, prepended to a space-separated list of filenames (which should probably be only the one because of `xargs -n`), then the current line which will include the `NUL` and other potentially terminal-confusing characters.

Comment: The issue was that join(" ",@ARGV) was the empty string - evidently the current file is `shift`ed off first, and $ARGV does in fact hold what I am looking for. Tricksy perlses! And yes it's mostly gibberish, i was debugging. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Pproceed something like this (I searched .pl files for "x" here):

```
find -type f -name \*.pl -print0 | \
xargs -0 \
perl -we 'while (<>) { print qq($ARGV\t$.\t$_) if m/x/ }'
```

And yes, it can be shortened using the `-n` switch:

```
find -type f -name \*.pl -print0 | \
xargs -0 \
perl -nwe 'print qq($ARGV\t$.\t$_) if m/x/'
```